# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'allRowsIDs.length') (React-Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm very new to React-Native. Following the basic React-Native tutorial I'm trying to fetch JSON data from "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json". I can display the `title` and `description` properties but when I try to display the "movies" property using a `ListView` I get the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'allRowsIDs.length')

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        dataSource: 'init',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.movies) });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your initial problem is that you've set `this.state.dataSource` to the string `'init'`.  You want that to be pointing to the datasource that you declared earlier.

You can solve your first problem, if you change:

```
this.state = { 
   dataSource: 'init',
};
```

to this:

```
this.state = {
   dataSource: ds
};
```

However, that's just going to get you to a new error message.  Something to the effect of `Objects are not valid as a React child...`.  You can fix that by changing your render function to return a simple string rather than the whole object.  I'll suggest you start with the title and move from there.  Try this and you should be on your way:

```
 render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.title}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be caused by trying to render `ListView` with a falsy list.

I just opened an app I hadn't used in like 6 months and it exploded fantastically because the database was wiped and this `ListView` was trying to render and getting an empty list from Redux `mapStateToProps`.

Long debug story short, I put an empty list check in the render method:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.employees.length) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>NO EMPLOYEES TO LIST</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    <ListView
      enableEmptySections
      dataSource={this.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
    />
  )
}
```

If you somehow keep getting it after that, put a falsy check in `renderRow`.

Answer (score 0):

According to react Native Documentation ***Listview Component is Deprecated*** in React Native. **Please use *FlatList* or *SectionList***

for more deails prefere:- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html